# Error in Ajax submit

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

I am new to Yii and ajax I want to read some inputs for a model from view and save it by using ajax. I used the following code inside form

```
<input type="button" name="save" value="save" onclick="saveFile()" id="profile-update" class="btn button-main" live="false">
```

and saveFile() is

```
function saveFile()
{
    var data;
    data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', $('#UserProfile_profile_picture')[0].files[0]);
    data.append('UserProfile', $('#profile-update-form').serialize());
    $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('user/profileupdate?rand=' . time())); ?>',
                type:"POST",
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false, 

                success: function (data) {
                    $("#AjaxLoader1").hide();  
                if(data.status=="success"){
                 $("#formResult1").html("Profile settings changed successfully.");
                 $("#profile-update-form")[0].reset();
                }
                 else{
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                $("#profile-update-form #"+key+"_em_").text(val);                                                    
                $("#profile-update-form #"+key+"_em_").show();
                });
                }
                },                    
             beforeSend: function(){                        
                   $("#AjaxLoader1").show();
              }
                }
            )
            return false;
}
```

and the code in controller is

```
$profile = UserProfile::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_id' => Yii::app()->user->id));
          if (!$profile) {
                $profile = new UserProfile;
                $profile->create_time = time();
                $profile->update_time = time();
          }
          if (isset($_POST['UserProfile'])) {
                $profile->attributes = $_POST['UserProfile'];
               $profile->profile_picture=$_FILES['file']['name'];
                   $images = CUploadedFile::getInstance($profile,'profile_picture');
                //  print_r($_POST);
                 //  print_r($profile->phone);
                //  print_r($images);
                  // exit();
                   if (isset($images))
                  {
                 if(!is_dir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/profilepic/'. 'quy'))
                  {
                  mkdir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/profilepic/'. $profile->profile_picture);
                  // the default implementation makes it under 777 permission, which you could possibly change recursively before deployment, but hereï¿½s less of a headache in case you donï¿½t
                  } 
                    foreach ($images as $image => $pic)
                     {
                         echo $pic->name;if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/profilepic/'.$pic->name))
                        {
                           $profile->profile_picture = $pic->name;
                       }
                  }
                  }
                $profile->user_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
                $profile->update_time = time();
                $valid = $profile->validate();
                $error = CActiveForm::validate(array($profile));
                if ($error == '[]') {
                    $profile->save(false);
                    echo CJSON::encode(array('status' => 'success'));
                    Yii::app()->end();
                } else {
                    $error = CActiveForm::validate(array($profile));
                    if ($error != '[]')
                        echo $error;
                    Yii::app()->end();
                    exit();
                }
          }
```

But here only the profile_picture is saving to the database all other fields are not changing. and the profile picture is not copying into the folder($images is blank) Please somebody help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please show us your form code?

Comment: @Ali '$profile->attributes = $_POST['UserProfile'];' this code is not working

Comment: while im printing print_r($_POST) it displays Array
(
    [UserProfile] => UserProfile%5Babout_me%5D=tyjtyjjy&UserProfile%5Bcity%5D=Delhiiii&UserProfile%5Bphone%5D=12111&UserProfile%5Bprofile_picture%5D=
) like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code   
`$profile->attributes = $_POST['UserProfile'];`  
 doesnt worked so i send it seperately by  
 `data.append('UserProfile[about_me]', $('#UserProfile_about_me').val());
        data.append('UserProfile[city]', $('#inputCity').val());
        data.append('UserProfile[phone]', $('#inputPhone').val());`   
and in controller i used   
`$profile->profile_picture=$_FILES['file']['name'];
                    $profile->about_me = $_POST['UserProfile']['about_me'];
                    $profile->city = $_POST['UserProfile']['city'];
                    $profile->phone = $_POST['UserProfile']['phone'];`  
 I know this is not the correct way but may be helpful for someone who is hurry.